# Gazebo: undefined symbol: _ZTIN6gazebo12CameraPluginE when creating camera plugin

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-plugin, ubuntu, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a camera plugin in gazebo 1.0.1. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on VMWare (MacOS Lion).
I don't know if I did all the steps in the correct way, so let me summarize:

I installed fuerte using the [official instructions](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu). I then followed both the instructions on [ROS](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/GazeboPluginIntro) and [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/tutorials/plugins) webpage to create plugins. I had no problems in creating a simple helloworld plugin or a plugin to move a box.

I am referring to this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/tutorials/plugins/camera_plugin) about the creation of a camera.

I created a package using

> roscreate-pkg camera_plugin gazebo roscpp std_msgs

then I copy-paste the suggested code in two different files put in src/ folder of my package.
I edited `CMakeLists.txt` in order to compile the plugins:

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
> include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

> rosbuild_init()

> set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)<br>
> set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

> rosbuild_add_library(CameraDump SHARED src/CameraDump.cpp)
> target_link_libraries(CameraDumb ${GAZEBO_libraries})

> rosbuild_add_library(CameraMove SHARED src/CameraMove.cpp)
> target_link_libraries(CameraMove ${GAZEBO_libraries} CameraPlugin)`

I compiled the code using `rosmake`, then I edited the default `empty.world` (after creating a backup copy) in order to add my plugins. I copy-paste the world suggested by the tutorial, then I launched gazebo using

> roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch.

Gazebo starts but I get as error:

> Error [Plugin.hh:100] Failed to load plugin /path/camera_plugin/lib/libCameraDump.so: /path/camera_plugin/lib/libCameraDump.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN6gazebo12CameraPluginE

Any suggestion on what may be the cause of this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35512/gazebo:-undefined-symbol:-_ztin6gazebo12cameraplugine-when-creating-camera-plugin/) by [Saphrosit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2516/saphrosit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 197 on 2012-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar issue and have actually been periodically checking this page for a solution.  However, I believe I have solved the issue (at least on my local machine).

The issue was an undefined symbol, thus pointing the error in the direction of the linking stage.  Then I realized it was because I was not linking the correct libraries.  It appears in your CMakeLists.txt above you have also made the same copy/paste mistake.

The CameraPlugin library should be linked with CameraDump, not CameraMove.  Thus if you update your target_link_libraries as below it may fix the issue.

```
target_link_libraries(CameraDump ${GAZEBO_libraries} CameraPlugin)
target_link_libraries(CameraMove ${GAZEBO_libraries})
```

---

Originally posted by [schadlerm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2603/schadlerm/) with karma: 86 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2